# Please merge [elastic-beanstalk] and [beanstalk]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [elastic-beanstalk](/questions/tagged/elastic-beanstalk) and [beanstalk](/questions/tagged/beanstalk) tags apparently have the same meaning. From what I know (which is very little) about Amazon Elastic Beanstalk is that [elastic-beanstalk](/questions/tagged/elastic-beanstalk) might be appropriate, and the tag wiki for [beanstalk](/questions/tagged/beanstalk) is better.

Can we merge these?

Comment: The images that are right now parading in my mind's eye, after having read that title... am I just wrong in the head somewhere?

Comment: Note that Beanstalk may also refer to [the code hosting service](http://beanstalkapp.com/) (not saying this is a good use of the tag, of course).

Comment: @CodyGray yea true. perhaps [beanstalkapp] would be appropriate.